# HTML 5 - anchors do not work with ios Safari

Tags: html, ios, safari, anchor

I have a fixed navigation bar which links to areas on the page via anchors - I have used HTML 5 "section" as opposed to a regular "div" but unsure if that makes any difference. When using a desktop with any of the main browsers these anchor links work fine as they do on an android tablet, however when using an ios device they do not respond, I have been searching for an alternative way of doing anchors for ios but to no conclusive fix.

Can anyone point me to a working alternative if there is one or a workaround?

Thanks, John

sample code:

```
<section id="headbar">

        <section class="container">
            <a href="#headbar" title="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="our logo"></a>

            <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#tour" title="Learn more" class="current">Tour</a></li>
            <li><a href="#faq" title="Frequently asked questions">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#terms" title="Contact us">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#terms" title="Read our terms">Terms</a></li>
            </ul><!-- End of #nav -->
        </section>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container          { width: 960px; margin: auto; }
#headbar            { background: url(../images/headbarbg.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent; height: 92px; position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 3000; }
/* Nav */
ul#nav              { list-style: none; float: right; }
ul#nav li           { float: left; padding: 0; font-size: 18px; width: auto; margin: 12px 15px 0 15px; }
ul#nav li a         { display:block; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; }
```

and how what they link to is coded:

```
<section id="tour">
    <section class="container">
    <h2>title here</2>
<p>lots of text</p>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Show sample HTML please. Maybe there's something wrong with it, but if you don't show it, how can we tell?

Comment: But what are those links links _to_? The question is how you've coded that. What are "tour", "faq", and "terms"?

Comment: Check out this link http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?259280-anchor-tag-not-working-in-safari-(ios)-for-Iphone-iTouch-iPad

Comment: And you've got a proper HTML 5 doctype? In that case this should work. I guess I'd suggesting experimenting attaching the id to something else instead of that section tag. Or try it in a very very simple test page (no javascript, no redirects, no nothing) and see if it works there.

Comment: Do you have a link that shows the problem? here a page with the structure you described and it seems to work in iOS. http://www.mx981.com/stuff/anchor.html

Comment: @Ruup I have seen that link before and disabling JS does indeed make it work but its not ideal.

Comment: @NicMagnier - I dont have a link but your mockup does not have position: fixed; for the headbar and I would guess no javascript but appreciate your efforts

Comment: position fixed. Following on Ruup suggestion, do you actually use javascripts in your page?

Comment: yes for automatic scrolling but have setup a mobile version which does not use JS however even without JS ios has problems as you can only use an anchor once before it then needs you to scroll yourself before you can click another..very strange.

Comment: You mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378527/anchors-losing-click-ability-after-scroll-on-ios-safari

Answer (score 0):

I am sure I read that html 5 anchors have to have id and name

```
<section id="tour" name="tour">
</section>
```